# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when running Java code through exec-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven

I have been struggling with this for hours now.

I am trying to run a Java class with maven and am getting the following error

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:294)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)
    at com.services.utils.EnvHandler.getProperty(EnvHandler.java:26)
    at com.services.agentsMonitor.MonitorAgentsTrigger.main(MonitorAgentsTrigger.java:77)


Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) on project SupportUtilities: 
An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: 
InvocationTargetException: NullPointerException
```

The thing is I have been able to execute the project successfully when running from eclipse but not from the command prompt

This  is my pom.xml where I have configured `exec-maven-plugin v1.5.0`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.services</groupId>
  <artifactId>SupportUtilities</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <mockito.version>1.9.0</mockito.version>
    <platform.messaging-jms-client.version>3.6.2.2</platform.messaging-jms-client.version>
    <tibco.jms.client.version>7.0.1</tibco.jms.client.version>
    <omslite.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</omslite.version>
    <logmon-parent-pom>2.2.2</logmon-parent-pom>
    <fasterxml.jackson.jsonSchema>2.4.0</fasterxml.jackson.jsonSchema>
    <fasterxml.jackson.databind>2.4.0</fasterxml.jackson.databind>
    <fasterxml.jackson.core>2.4.0</fasterxml.jackson.core>
    <ojdbc6.version>12.1.0.2.0</ojdbc6.version>
    <commons-lang.version>2.1</commons-lang.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
    <json-simple.version>1.1</json-simple.version>
    <apache.commons.io.version>1.4.0</apache.commons.io.version>
    <netty.version>3.2.10.Final</netty.version>
    <javax.jms.version>1.1</javax.jms.version>
    <org.slf4j.version>1.6.2</org.slf4j.version>
    <joda-time.version>2.9</joda-time.version>
    <sling.commons.json.version>2.0.12</sling.commons.json.version>
    <jsch.version>0.1.51</jsch.version>
    <xercesImpl.version>2.8.0</xercesImpl.version>
    <httpclient.version>4.5.1</httpclient.version>
    <javax.mail.version>1.5.0-b01</javax.mail.version>
    <poi-ooxml.version>3.9</poi-ooxml.version>
    <JSON4J.version>1.1.0</JSON4J.version>
    <exec-maven-plugin.version>3.1</exec-maven-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>${ojdbc6.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${json-simple.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.commons.io.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
        <version>${netty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tibco.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>tibco_jms</artifactId>
        <version>${tibco.jms.client.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.jms.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.walmart.platform.messaging</groupId>
        <artifactId>messaging-jms-client</artifactId>
        <version>${platform.messaging-jms-client.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.sling.commons.json</artifactId>
        <version>${sling.commons.json.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>${jsch.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>${xercesImpl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.mail.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${poi-ooxml.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>JSON4J</artifactId>
        <version>${JSON4J.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${fasterxml.jackson.core}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${fasterxml.jackson.databind}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-jsonSchema</artifactId>
        <version>${fasterxml.jackson.jsonSchema}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </plugin> 
        <!-- <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin> -->
    </plugins>

  </build>

</project>
```

The problem is that my code is not able to load a file that is located in my resources folder.

Below is the code for the EnvHandler Class that is there in my `com.services.util`s package

```
public Properties getProperty(String env, String mgmtSystem) throws IOException {

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream propFile = null;


        /*
         * Loading based on OMS/IMS
         */

        if("OMS".equalsIgnoreCase(mgmtSystem)) {
            /*
             * Loading the properties file based on environment qa/qa2/prod
             */
            if("qa".equalsIgnoreCase(env)) {

                propFile = EnvHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/Services/agentsMonitor/OMS/Credentials_qa.properties");   //I have error here
                System.out.println("PropFile->" + propFile.toString());
                prop.load(propFile);
                return prop;

            }
            else if("qa2".equalsIgnoreCase(env)) {

                propFile = EnvHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/Services/agentsMonitor/OMS/Credentials_qa2.properties");
                prop.load(propFile);
                return prop;

            }else if("prod".equalsIgnoreCase(env)) {

                propFile = EnvHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/Services/agentsMonitor/OMS/Credentials_prod.properties");
                prop.load(propFile);
                return prop;

            }
        } else if("IMS".equalsIgnoreCase(mgmtSystem)) {
            /*
             * Loading the properties file based on environment qa/qa2/prod
             */
            if("qa".equalsIgnoreCase(env)) {

                propFile = EnvHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/Services/agentsMonitor/IMS/Credentials_qa.properties");     
                prop.load(propFile);
                return prop;

            }
            else if("qa2".equalsIgnoreCase(env)) {

                propFile = EnvHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/Services/agentsMonitor/IMS/Credentials_qa2.properties");
                prop.load(propFile);
                return prop;

            }else if("prod".equalsIgnoreCase(env)) {

                propFile = EnvHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/Services/agentsMonitor/IMS/Credentials_prod.properties");
                prop.load(propFile);
                return prop;

            }
        }


        return null;

}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Please comment if you need any more information

Update: Below is my project structure

```
--src/main/java
     --com.services.agentsMonitor
         --MonitorAgentsForTrigger.java
     --com.services.logsMonitor
         --MonitorLogsForConnectionIssues.java
     --com.services.utils
         --EnvHandler.java
--src/main/resources
     --com.services.agentsMonitor
         --OMS
             --Credentials_qa.properties
             --Credentials_qa2.properties
             --Credentials_prod.properties  
         --IMS
             --Credentials_qa.properties
             --Credentials_qa2.properties
             --Credentials_prod.properties
```

Comment: @Jens Updated the folder structure

Comment: @Jens What do you mean, those are packages

Comment: @Jens as I said in my question, it works in eclipse but not from commandline

Comment: @Jens Yes the files are there in the jar, I had experienced a weird thing today, I changed the exec-maven-plugin version to 2.0, which produced an error that version not found, and then changed it back to 1.5.0 and one among the two classes started working on my local, however it still doesn't work from jenkins on a host server

Comment: @Jens , I was able to solve the problem using `getContextClassLoader()`. I have added that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been struggling with this for days till I find that the error is because when running in windows the reourceUrl is not treated to be case sensitive, but when running on a unix machine it is treated case Sensitive, so the resource had mentioned `com/Services` instead of `/com/services`

```
if("OMS".equalsIgnoreCase(mgmtSystem)) {
        /*
         * Loading the properties file based on environment qa/qa2/prod
         */
        if("qa".equalsIgnoreCase(env)) {

            propFile = EnvHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/services/agentsMonitor/OMS/Credentials_qa.properties");   //I have error here
            System.out.println("PropFile->" + propFile.toString());
            prop.load(propFile);
            return prop;

        }
        else if("qa2".equalsIgnoreCase(env)) {

            propFile = EnvHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/services/agentsMonitor/OMS/Credentials_qa2.properties");
            prop.load(propFile);
            return prop;

        }else if("prod".equalsIgnoreCase(env)) {

            propFile = EnvHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/services/agentsMonitor/OMS/Credentials_prod.properties");
            prop.load(propFile);
            return prop;

        }
    } else if("IMS".equalsIgnoreCase(mgmtSystem)) {
        /*
         * Loading the properties file based on environment qa/qa2/prod
         */
        if("qa".equalsIgnoreCase(env)) {

            propFile = EnvHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/services/agentsMonitor/IMS/Credentials_qa.properties");     
            prop.load(propFile);
            return prop;

        }
        else if("qa2".equalsIgnoreCase(env)) {

            propFile = EnvHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/services/agentsMonitor/IMS/Credentials_qa2.properties");
            prop.load(propFile);
            return prop;

        }else if("prod".equalsIgnoreCase(env)) {

            propFile = EnvHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/services/agentsMonitor/IMS/Credentials_prod.properties");
            prop.load(propFile);
            return prop;

        }
    }
```